# How to change the url sent to the browser node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, express

I am trying to change the location displayed in the url bar. In my code I am being directed to a particular route through the client

```
    var user = "matt";
    window.location.href = "/profile/:" + user;
```

Then on my server I have tried doing this, but it just sets the response header not the actual url displayed

```
app.get('/profile/:user', function (req, res) {
        var user = req.param('user');
        res.setHeader("Location",user);
        res.render('profile', {
            title: 'Profile page'
        });
})
```

So when the profile page is rendered I want the user to see mysitename/matt isntead of mysitename/profile/:user.I know it is possible on the client to manipulate the url like this

```
history.pushstate(null, null, '/matt')
```

But I want to change the url on the server instead, so somehow strip /profile from the url sent to the client and only have the /:user. Can someone point me in the right direction to implementing this on the server side on node.js Thanks

Comment: The server doesn't "send a URL" at all.  Are you asking how to send a redirect response?

Comment: thanks for responding, i am asking on how to edit the address of the url sent back by the server, so right now when the route "profile/:user" is requested the url that is sent back to the server is mysite/profile/:user i want to remove profile from the address so that the url in the browser address bar is mysite/:user

Comment: Just do `res.redirect(user)`